# Laravel App Struture/Architecture

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am writing a Laravel app which basically allows you to run tournaments in various formats. Now the problem I have is that I want the same route for each of the different tournament formats. Each format has very different logic and views.

At first I just had a single TournamentController and used if statements in each function to check the type and execute the appropriate logic for example:

```
public function start($tournamentId){

    $tournament = Tournament::find($tournamentId);

    if($tournament->type == "single elimination"){

       //single elimination logic

    }elseif($tournament->type == "round robin"){

      //round robin logic

    }

}
```

Now I realise as I add more tournament types, having this type of logic in every function in the TournamentController is going to get messy. So then I created two separate Controllers, SingleEliminationController and RoundRobinController, and in the routes file I made the controllers dynamic by doing something like:

```
    $tournament = Tournament::find(Request::segment(2));

    $controller = str_replace(' ', '', $tournament->tournamentType());

Route::get('{tournamentId}/{slug}', $controller . 'Controller@showTournament')->where('tournamentId', '[0-9]+');
```

This seems a bit more manageable, but it still seems a bit hacky, I'm sure there's got to be a better way to structure things but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Worth noting: http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/Clean_Code_Args.pdf

Comment: @cwallenpoole , well .. the OP doesn't even see the problem with using global scope. I doubt that your linked material will have ANY impact.

Comment: @tereško Please feel free to post more helpful comments

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Route::get('{tournamentId}/{tournamentType}', function($tournamentId, $tournamentType){
    $controllerName = studly_case($tournamentType).'Controller';
    return App::make($controllerName)->showTournament($tournamentId);
})->where(array(
    'tournamentId' => '[0-9]+',
    'tournamentType' => '(single elimination|round robin)'
));
```

Add every `tournamentType` to the where condition, so if a type is entered that does not exist, the route gets skipped.

By the way: I suggest you change your tournament types to something without *spaces* since they can be problematic in urls. e.g. `single-elimination`

**Edit**

If you have controller filters, or want to do it a bit more "clean"

```
return App::make($controllerName)->callAction('showTournament', array($tournamentId));
```

Comment: Note that this breaks controller-level before/after filters.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thats true. I added an alternative that should keep controller filters working

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what advantages does this provide over the way I'm doing it atm, as there are many other routes I would need to do this for aswell.

Comment: @user3134962 The slug gets validated (via the where condition) and its cleaner because your actual route doesn't change from request to request